# Regarding Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I am new to Maven and if you feel i am asking really basic question then please forgive me.

I am facing couple of problems with Maven mentioned below.

I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 (Which comes with the Maven Plugin).Now i installed two plugins..out of which one is for subclipse(with SVNKit) and m2e-Subclipse which is used for integrating the maven with SVN.I downloaded the project in eclipse using svn plugin as "checkout as Maven project" and i could see the project being downloaded and now to remove all the errors related with the POM.XML i downloaded the Maven and given the local path of the Maven in the  preferences > Maven > installations and changed the Global Settings and user settings files which are project specific.

1). Now even after doing all this circus i still can not see the Maven build options in my Eclipse.
2). I am not even able to clean the project from command prompt.
when i go to my project directory and type "mvn -version" which shows me the correct version of maven.

But when i try to clean it using mvn clean. it does not work.

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide output of mvn clean command. Also, how are you invoking mvn clean? From command line or via Eclipse - and if latter, be precise in what series of menu items you're clicking and typing.

Comment: I am able to sort out it.It was a certificate error while building it.I added the certificate as trusted in JRE cacerts using keytool.